# Setting focus on a field after going to a new record on a sub form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know how to instruct the cursor to arrive on a specific field in a sub form for when creating a record via the 'acNewRec' do command.

At present I have created a sub routine on my sub form which aims to create a new record and allow the user to land on the field 'MacroProcess':

```
Sub GoToNewRecord()

     DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
     Me.MacroProcess.SetFocus

End Sub
```

To execute this sub routine (on the sub form) the following routine is built on an object in my main form:

```
Private Sub cmdDetails_Click()

     Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.AllowAdditions = True
     Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.AllowEdits = True
     Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.AllowDeletions = True
     Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.GoToNewRecord

End Sub
```

From the main form, the goToNewRecord command functions correctly and brings the user to the sub form however the result does not show me a flashing cursor on the newly created record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07` the name of the subform? It's a weird solution and I can't take credit because I read it [here](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.access.forms/setfocus-to-a-control-on-a-subf/70120), but if you get rid of the `GoToNewRecord` subroutine altogether, then change this code, it seems to work. I don't know why doing it in this order (ie, setting the focus BEFORE going to the new record) works, but it does put the cursor in the textbox when I tested it with my Access.

```
    Private Sub cmdDetails_Click()
         Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.AllowAdditions = True
         Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.AllowEdits = True
         Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.AllowDeletions = True

         'First set the focus to the subform itself
         Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.SetFocus
         'Now set the focus to the textbox on the subform
         Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.Form.MacroProcess.SetFocus
         'Now tell the subform to go to a new record
         Form_frmstaticdatadepartments07.Form.GoToNewRecord
    End Sub
```

Comment: Mr. Toomey. It doesnt seem to like the last line (GoToNewRecord). I am getting the error message 'Impossible to find the method or the data member'   (That is the Italian translatoin of my error message. perhaps the english version of Access is different)

Comment: I'm using Access 2003. Are you on a newer version? They might've changed that command. How about if you make the last line  "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew", does that work?

Comment: Thank you again Mr. Toomey! I am using MS Access 2013. You were right with that last ammendment. Works great!